How to get request body data in nginx log
I am using nginx 1.19 version. I have configured the proxy for tomcat in the below nginx.conf file and I have no problem with it, I just want to print the request body in the log file.
nginx.conf
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  mainapplicare  '$remote_addr - $remote_user $time_iso8601 [$request_time] "$request" '
    #                   '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                   '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user $time_iso8601 [$request_time] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
                    
    access_log  logs/newlogfolder/access.log  main;


            
   
    

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    upstream applicare {
            ip_hash;
            server 192.168.1.6:8880;
    }
            
    server {
        listen       85;
        server_name  192.168.1.6;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root html;
            index index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass_request_body on;
            proxy_pass http://applicare;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            # Enable writing request body to temporary file
            client_body_in_file_only on;

            access_log logs/access.log main;  # Your existing access log
        }
        
        location /nginx-status {
                 stub_status on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
        }
        

        
        #location / {
        #proxy_pass http://applicare;
        #}

        

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}


I added below line in location in nginx.conf file but request body is not printed as I expected.
client_body_buffer_size 10k;  
client_max_body_size 1m;     
client_body_in_file_only on;

In the nginx log file, the data is printed as shown below, and the request body should also be printed along with it.
192.168.1.12 - - 2024-05-31T10:24:51-04:00 [0.007] "GET /applicare/agent?q=getMysnmpDevices&name=L12-RHEL7_sa&clientId=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (java 1.5)" "-"
